# doctrine have value persist but null when flush

Tags: zend-framework, doctrine-orm

I had checked and it have value but when flush(), it's null with level. I had created fk in database.Message: An exception occurred while executing 'INSERT INTO user (username, password, real_name, level) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)' with params {"1":"abcdef","2":"21232f297a57a5a743894a0e4a801fc3","3":"abcdef","4":null}: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'level' cannot be null 
My code in controller

```
public function testinsertAction()
{
    $user = new \Entities\Usernew();
    $user->setUsername('abcdef');
    $user->setPassword(MD5('admin'));
    $user->setReal_name('abcdef');
    $user->setLevel(1);
    $this->_em->persist($user);
    \Zend_Debug::dump($user);die();
    $this->_em->flush();
}
```

Entities

```
namespace Entities;
/**
 * @Entity 
 * @Table(name="user")  
 */
class Usernew{
/**
 * @id
 * @Column(type="integer",length=11)
 * @GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
protected $id;


/**
 * @Column(type="string",length=50)
 */
protected $username;
/**
 * @Column(type="string",length=32)
 */
protected $password;
/**
 * @Column(type="string",length=150,nullable=true)
 */
protected $real_name;
/**
 * @Column(type="integer",length=1)
 * 
 */
protected $level;
/**
 * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="Level", inversedBy="users")
 * @JoinColumn(name="level",referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $group;
/**
 * @return the $group
 */
public function getGroup()
{
    return $this->group;
}

/**
 * @param field_type $group
 */
public function setGroup($group)
{
    $this->group = $group;
}
/**
 * @return the $password
 */
public function getPassword()
{
    return $this->password;
}
/**
 * @param field_type $password
 */
public function setPassword($password)
{
    $this->password = $password;
}
/**
 * @return the $id
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * @return the $username
 */
public function getUsername()
{
    return $this->username;
}

/**
 * @return the $real_name
 */
public function getReal_name()
{
    return $this->real_name;
}

/**
 * @return the $level
 */
public function getLevel()
{
    return $this->level;
}

/**
 * @param field_type $id
 */
public function setId($id)
{
    $this->id = $id;
}

/**
 * @param field_type $username
 */
public function setUsername($username)
{
    $this->username = $username;
}

/**
 * @param field_type $real_name
 */
public function setReal_name($real_name)
{
    $this->real_name = $real_name;
}

/**
 * @param field_type $level
 */
public function setLevel($level)
{
    $this->level = $level;
}
```

My Entities\Level

```
namespace Entities;
use \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
/**
 * @Entity
 * @Table(name="level")
 */
class Level{
/**
 * @id
 * @Column(type="integer",length=11)
 * @GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 * 
 */
protected $id;
/**
 * @Column(type="string",length=150,nullable=true)
 */
protected $name;
/**
 * @OnetoMany(targetEntity="Usernew", mappedBy="group")
 */
protected $users;
/**
 * @return the $id
 */
public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

/**
 * @return the $name
 */
public function getName()
{
    return $this->name;
}

/**
 * @return the $users
 */
public function getUsers()
{
    return $this->users;
}

/**
 * @param field_type $id
 */
public function setId($id)
{
    $this->id = $id;
}

/**
 * @param field_type $name
 */
public function setName($name)
{
    $this->name = $name;
}

/**
 * @param \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection $users
 */
public function setUsers($users)
{
    $this->users = $users;
}
public function __construct(){
    $this->users= new ArrayCollection();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The foreign key `level` cannot be null, either check the field in `phpMyAdmin` in your **table structure** to allow null values or in your case as it is **fk** so you have to insert some value, Foreign key should not be null any way